# cleveref fails to reference algorithms

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms, cleveref, algorithmicx

In the following example document, both `\autoref` and plain `ref` will correctly link and number an algorithm reference, but `cleveref` fails that task. It will just insert question marks instead. In another, far more complex document I have, it does insert correct numbers but links them all to page 1. Since the documentation of `cleveref` sounds like it should support everything other referencing packages support and more, I'd have hoped this was supported, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\providecommand\algorithmname{algorithm}
\begin{document}
We want the real content on page two to better detect errors.
\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Incrementation step}\label{alg:inc}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $x\gets x+1$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Comparing auto like \autoref{alg:inc},
clever like \cref{alg:inc} % this gives the error message
and manual like algorithm~\ref{alg:inc}.
\end{document}
```

Compiling the above I get

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `alg:inc' on page 1 undefined on input line 18.
```

If I move the `algorithm` package before `cleveref`, I get an error instead of that warning:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ALG@beginalgorithmic 

l.2843   }{}
            %  end of \@ifpackageloaded{algorithm}
```

But if I move the `algpseudocode` before `cleveref`, I'm back to the beginning.

This is a Gentoo texlive 2012 installation, with the following packages involved:

- cleveref 2012/03/07 v0.18.5
- hyperref 2012/05/13 v6.82q
- algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1
- algorithmicx 2005/04/27 v1.2

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113403/how-to-use-nameref-with-algorithm2e

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Looks more like the opposite of what I have in my more complex real world example: that question describes a situation where links work but text fails, whereas my real document has correct text but broken links. The example above is broken in both ways. I whish I knew why these differences. But the solution to that question appears to be specific to `algorithm2e` which I don't use. And probably won't use any time soon, since it [doesn't seem to integrate well with my other plans](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113727/16923).

Comment: Please also note that your version of `cleveref` is quite old (dare I say obsolete?). The most recent version is 0.18.9; among its improvements are several updates to keep up with recent changes in some of the algo packages... You may want to update all of these packages.

Comment: @Mico: I had *hoped* that using a texlive 2012 install just as my distro provides it would maximize interoperability between packages. Things might be old, but as long as they should be equally old… However, I noticed that my Gentoo Texlive 2012 comes with `mdframed` v1.6b, as opposed to the v1.5 on my OS X. And 1.6b requires [a fix](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/commit/f74e9e3751c9526b5d368989df8aeac37472d91b) to work with `amsthm`. So my belief that unmodified texlive releases would be a good foundation for portability is not as strong as it used to be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use the correct loading order; check also
[Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/16923)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% hyperref must go last
\usepackage{hyperref}

% but cleveref goes "laster" than hyperref
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\providecommand\algorithmname{algorithm}

\begin{document}
We want the real content on page two to better detect errors.
\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Incrementation step}\label{alg:inc}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $x\gets x+1$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Comparing auto like \autoref{alg:inc},
clever like \cref{alg:inc}
and manual like algorithm~\ref{alg:inc}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had hoped it would be something as easy to fix as this. Easy once you know what to do, that is. Is there some way to figure out correct package order, short of reading all the docs of all involved packages, or trial and error? I know I had read somewhere that hyperref should go last, but on the other hand I figured that a lot of other packages will probably depend on hyprref, so just because I list it last won't mean it gets included last.

Comment: @MvG A rule of thumb is that `hyperref` goes last; however a few package should go after it: `cleveref` is the main one, but also `bookmark` (that provides easier management of PDF bookmarks).

Comment: I just got [a pointer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113727/algoritms-in-mdframed#comment250829_113735) to “[Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/16923)”. Might be a good reference in this context here, since it has some more packages that go after `hyperref`. Seems that is one package where order is particularly important. Thanks for your help in this!