# Algorithms in mdframed

Tags: algorithms, mdframed, algorithmicx

Now that I converted all my theorems to [`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed), I'd like a consistent layout for my algorithms as well? What ways are there to typeset pseudocode algorithms in `mdframed`?

So far I've been using `algorithm.sty` from the [`algorithms`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) bundle, together with `algpseudocode.sty` from the [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). But since that looks completely different, and has [problems with `cleveref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113719/16923) as well, I'm looking for alternatives.

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) on its own looks nice enough, but since that comes with its own float environment, I get an error `Not in outer par mode` when I try to plug that into an `mdframed` theorem environment.

[algorithmicx](/questions/tagged/algorithmicx) does not insist on outer par mode, but so far I haven't managed to get that working directly inside a frame either. For some reason, I get a lot of error messages I didn't get before, like label names having an extra `}`, or like `destination with the same identifier (name{ALG@line.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`.

In an ideal world, a suitable solution would offer

- References for the whole algorithm as well as individual lines
- Flexible line numbering
- Flexible syntax formatting
- Allow page breaks withing algorithms
- Other bells and whistles to make things look nice

Comment: I do think `algorithmic` bundle w/wo the `algorithmicx` can do the job, filling all your requirements.

Comment: @cacamailg: You are right, things look good now. I've been looking for the wrong package to blame: having `algorithm` and `cleveref` both loaded as well will break things, without `mdframed` being in any way involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I'd say: the main conflict was between `algorithms` and `cleveref`, without regard for `hyperref`, since I already had `cleveref` after `hyperref`, thanks to [an answer by egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113726/16923). And just because the currently accepted answer uses the packages I already mentioned, I'd still love to hear about other alternatives, like perhaps some way to put an `algorithm2e`-style layout with lines and all those bells and whistles into an `mdframed` environment.

Comment: Getting this to work with algorithm2e would be great...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't managed to get [[algorithmicx](/questions/tagged/algorithmicx)] working directly inside a frame either.

I was wrong in assuming that [mdframed](/questions/tagged/mdframed) was to blame: it was [cleveref](/questions/tagged/cleveref) interfering. When that detects a package called `algorithm`, it will try to modify its code, apparently breaking things for [algorithmicx](/questions/tagged/algorithmicx). By not including that package, things worked a lot better.

At some point, I had the impression that I needed the `algorithm` package in order to get some of my symbols defined. I can't reproduce this any more, but if anyone should really need that package, here is a package loading order which seems to work as well, since it prevents [cleveref](/questions/tagged/cleveref) from interfering with [algorithmix](/questions/tagged/algorithmix):

1. `hyperref`
2. `cleveref`
3. `algorithm`
4. `algpseudocode`

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before