# Input variables in parenthesis in caption of algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

I would like two things

1. Have the list of input parameters shown in paranthesis behind the caption of the algorithm, but hidden in the algorithm (the traditional "intput: X,Y,Z" ).
2. Be able to reference the caption without the input in parenthesis.

The desired output should look like this:
[image: Desired output]

My code looks like this. It wasn't used to generate the desired output seen above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,commentsnumbered,resetcount,noalgohanging,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{ex}
\nameref{abc} - Should read 'HowToWriteAlgorithms' without the input in parenthesis\\
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{HowToWriteAlgorithms}
    \label{abc}
    \KwIn{x}
    \While{not at end of this document}{Try this}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`algorithm2e` requires a patch to function correctly with `\nameref{}` as explained in [How to use Nameref with Algorithm2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113403/how-to-use-nameref-with-algorithm2e)

In addition to that, to have a different caption text inside of the algorithm and outside (`\nameref`,`listofalgorithms`) use the optional argument of `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,commentsnumbered,resetcount,noalgohanging,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Patch of algorithm2e according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113403/how-to-use-nameref-with-algorithm2e
\makeatletter
\let\original@algocf@latexcaption\algocf@latexcaption
\long\def\algocf@latexcaption#1[#2]{%
  \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
    \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
  }{%
    \NR@gettitle{#2}%
  }%
  \original@algocf@latexcaption{#1}[{#2}]%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\section{ex}\label{sec:ex}

\nameref{abc} - Should read 'HowToWriteAlgorithms' without the input in parenthesis\\
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption[HowToWriteAlgorithms]{HowToWriteAlgorithms(X,Y,Z)
    \label{abc}
    }
    %\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}
    %\TitleOfAlgo{HowToWriteAlgorithms(X,Y,Z)}
    \KwIn{x}
    \While{not at end of this document}{Try this}
\end{algorithm}

A reference to algorithm \nameref{abc}

\listofalgorithms
\end{document}
```

[image]